# Photolectric effect - ligth intensity and frequency

Tags: photoelectric-effect

To my best knowledge the intensity of light determines the rate of electron emission and the frequency of light determines whether electrons will be ejected and their maximum kinetic energy.

If frequency is increased but intensity remains the same:

- electrons will get more kinetic energy (larger speed)
- the rate of emission of electrons will remain the same

However, as I am solving the following exercise and checking the answers after that, I discover that the rate of emission will decrease. Assuming that the answer is not incorrect, why would it decrease?

[image]

Comment: This is not a complete anwer but an idea (it should be correct though).
Intensity is measured as $W/m^2$ and the power is given by number of photons per unit time times the energy of each photon so $I=\frac{Power}{Area}=\frac{Energy}{\Delta t \cdot Area}=\frac{h \cdot f \cdot N_{photons}}{\Delta t \cdot Area}$. This means that you can increase frequency, decrease photon number accordingly and you will keep the same intensity. Since each photon interacts with one electron you will decrease the rate of emission.